# How to show "busy" dialog (spinning wheel) on Smart Phone

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

Can't find how it is called nor how to pop it up.

My CF application is talking over the web with a web service. Want to show my user some "busy activity" dialog.

Any suggestions how to show the default one from WinMo?

Comment: Yep. Found it myself after 4 hours of search (expected a dialog instead):

            Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following should work...

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
...
Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
```